# Why are stringify'd moment.js dates returning different values when parsed back

Tags: javascript, utc, momentjs

I have a moment that I want to store in local storage and compare against at a later date using [isBefore()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/).

When I stringify this moment [it converts it](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-json/) to ISO8601 format, fine. However when I try to bring this string back into play by turning it into a new moment it has a different value. The hour is getting offset by a timezone conversion.

It goes like this:

`moment().hour();` = 21

`JSON.stringify(moment());` = "2013-05-20T21:38:31.819Z"`

`moment("2013-05-20T21:38:31.819Z").hour();` = 22

Obviously the issue here is related to the fact ISO8601 is in UTC format but no matter how I try to use the moment utc() function it doesn't change the fact the fundamental values underneath are different.

How can I stringify a moment and then parse it again with the value remaining contant?

Comment: Hope solution in this link helps <https://stackoverflow.com/a/31104671/10265076>?

Comment: Hope solution in this link helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/31104671/10265076

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I have for this is to force moment to not use utc when converting the string. So, where foobar is the object sotred in local storage, if:

`foobar.expires` = `2013-05-22T15:30:23.834Z`

then the statement:

`moment(foobar.expires, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS")`

will return the same moment that was originally stringify'd when it was stored in local storage.

Messy hack though.

Comment: The correct format string would be: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS"