# How to JSON stringify a javascript Date and preserve timezone

Tags: javascript, json, date, datetime, momentjs

I have a date object that's created by the user, with the timezone filled in by the browser, like so:

```
var date = new Date(2011, 05, 07, 04, 0, 0);
> Tue Jun 07 2011 04:00:00 GMT+1000 (E. Australia Standard Time)
```

When I stringify it, though, the timezone goes bye-bye

```
JSON.stringify(date);
> "2011-06-06T18:00:00.000Z"
```

The best way I can get a ISO8601 string while preserving the browser's timezone is by using moment.js and using `moment.format()`, but of course that won't work if I'm serializing a whole command via something that uses `JSON.stringify` internally (in this case, AngularJS)

```
var command = { time: date, contents: 'foo' };
$http.post('/Notes/Add', command);
```

For completeness, my domain *does* need both the local time and the offset.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Assuming you have some kind of object that contains a `Date`:

```
var o = { d : new Date() };
```

You can override the `toJSON` function of the `Date` prototype.  Here I use moment.js to create a `moment` object from the date, then use moment's `format` function without parameters, which emits the ISO8601 extended format including the offset.

```
Date.prototype.toJSON = function(){ return moment(this).format(); }
```

Now when you serialize the object, it will use the date format you asked for:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(o);  //  '{"d":"2015-06-28T13:51:13-07:00"}'
```

Of course, that will affect *all* `Date` objects.  If you want to change the behavior of only the specific date object, you can override just that particular object's `toJSON` function, like this:

```
o.d.toJSON = function(){ return moment(this).format(); }
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint about overriding the toJSON method, that indeed solved my problem. but is there any safe way of doing it? I mean if I override it, It will be overridden everywhere, and it will mess .stringify elsewhere if I were using it.

Comment: @KamyarGhasemlou - Updated the question to show one way.  You can change a single `Date` object instance's `toJSON` function instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and quick addition. I should have thought about overriding method for a specific object, very clever. :)

Comment: Saved a good night sleep :) I was stuck on this for quite some while. Just import and override it in the module.js (angular 2+)

Answer (score 64):

I'd always be inclined to not mess with functions in the prototype of system objects like the date, you never know when that's going to bite you in some unexpected way later on in your code.

Instead, the JSON.stringify method accepts a "replacer" function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) which you can supply, allowing you to override the innards of how JSON.stringify performs its "stringification"; so you could do something like this;

```js
var replacer = function(key, value) {

   if (this[key] instanceof Date) {
      return this[key].toUTCString();
   }
   
   return value;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(new Date(), replacer));
console.log(JSON.stringify({ myProperty: new Date()}, replacer));
console.log(JSON.stringify({ myProperty: new Date(), notADate: "I'm really not", trueOrFalse: true}, replacer));
```

Comment: I just realized that I cannot mess with `value` as well. Have to use `this[key]`.

Comment: @Polv yea it's not the most intuitive!

Comment: To save others the same struggle: replacer is called recursively, where `this` is the current node of the object, `key` the property being converted, and `value` a pre-transformed property value, being a string when original was a Date. Hence: `this[key]`, which gives you a Date rather than `value`, which gives you a string.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much for this (no pun intended). It's worth it pointing out though that `this[key]` won't work in arrow functions.

Comment: @GrimaceofDespair I just wasted so much time on this! Do you have any idea why `this[key]` and `value` are *not* the same thing? I couldn't find any documentation about it.

Comment: @Shawson is there an equivalent of this for `JSON.parse` ?

Comment: There is, the parse method supports "revivers" which do the same as replacers, but in reverse! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 36):

Based on Matt Johnsons 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31104671/803336), I re-implemented `toJSON` without having to depend on `moment` (which I think is a splendid library, but a dependency in such a low level method like `toJSON` bothers me).

```js
Date.prototype.toJSON = function () {
  var timezoneOffsetInHours = -(this.getTimezoneOffset() / 60); //UTC minus local time
  var sign = timezoneOffsetInHours >= 0 ? '+' : '-';
  var leadingZero = (Math.abs(timezoneOffsetInHours) < 10) ? '0' : '';

  //It's a bit unfortunate that we need to construct a new Date instance 
  //(we don't want _this_ Date instance to be modified)
  var correctedDate = new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), 
      this.getDate(), this.getHours(), this.getMinutes(), this.getSeconds(), 
      this.getMilliseconds());
  correctedDate.setHours(this.getHours() + timezoneOffsetInHours);
  var iso = correctedDate.toISOString().replace('Z', '');

  return iso + sign + leadingZero + Math.abs(timezoneOffsetInHours).toString() + ':00';
}
```

The `setHours` method will adjust other parts of the date object when the provided value would "overflow". From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours%20MDN):

> If a parameter you specify is outside of the expected range, setHours() attempts to update the date information in the Date object accordingly. For example, if you use 100 for secondsValue, the minutes will be incremented by 1 (minutesValue + 1), and 40 will be used for seconds.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to allow for minutes in the timezone offset. ie. `var offsetMinutes = this.getTimezoneOffset() % 60`

Comment: I think I would use a solution like this if I didn't already have moment js as a dependency

Comment: @JonathanWilson: I'm unsure why you would need the remaining minutes. Afaik, a timezone offset is always a whole number of hours.

Comment: you are correct that it usually is whole hours but I know for a fact that there are timezone offsets with minutes too. Nepal, for example is +05:45. I think it's a good idea when posting a general solution about time and timezones, to make it as robust as possible.

Comment: @Endless, as per your demands, I removed `: string` (three places) and `: Date` (one place). Now it's plain javascript.

Comment: Further to @JonathanWilson: Australia has non-hour based timezones as well

Comment: Unfortunately this answer does not work for non integer timezones (Adelaide Australia UTC +9.5, Marquesas Islands UTC -9.5. I'll post a modified solution that does work correctly

Answer (score 13):

> When I stringify it, though, the timezone goes bye-bye

That’s because `Tue Jun 07 2011 04:00:00 GMT+1000 (E. Australia Standard Time)` is actually the result of the `toString` method of the `Date` object, whereas `stringify` seems to call the `toISOString` method instead.

So if the `toString` format is what you want, then simply stringify *that*:

```
JSON.stringify(date.toString());
```

Or, since you want to stringify your “command” later on, put *that* value in there in the first place:

```
var command = { time: date.toString(), contents: 'foo' };
```

Comment: I get that I can just do it myself, but I'm after a way of doing it with an existing object. It's pretty dodgy having to translate the whole object when I just want to specify how one part serializes.

Comment: You can `date.toJSON = function () { return this.toString(); }` to specify how you want to stringify just this 'date' of your whole object.

Comment: `toString` might have the offset, but it's not in ISO format.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a small library that preserves the timezone with ISO8601 string after `JSON.stringify`. The library lets you easily alter the behavior of the native `Date.prototype.toJSON` method.

npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lbdate

Example:

```js
lbDate().init();

const myObj = {
  date: new Date(),
};

const myStringObj = JSON.stringify(myObj);

console.log(myStringObj);

// {"date":"2020-04-01T03:00:00.000+03:00"}
```

The library also gives you options to customize the serialization result if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a JS Date Object and want to stringify it to preserve the timezone, then you should definitely use `toLocaleDateString()`.
It is a very powerful helper function that can help you format your Date object in every way possible.

For example, if you want to print "**Friday, February 1, 2019, Pacific Standard Time**",

```
 const formatDate = (dateObject : Date) => {
    const options: any  = {
        weekday: 'long',
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'long',
        day: 'numeric',
        timeZoneName: 'long'
      };
      
    return dateObject.toLocaleDateString('en-CA', options);
  };
```

Thus, by modifying the `options` object, you can achieve different styles of formatting for your Date Object.

**For more information regarding the ways of formatting, refer to this Medium article:** https://medium.com/swlh/use-tolocaledatestring-to-format-javascript-dates-2959108ea020

Answer (score 0):

let date  = new Date(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new Date(2011, 05, 07, 04, 0, 0))));

Answer (score 0):

bvgheluwe's answer providing a modified Date.prototype.toJSON() is a good start, but does not work for non-integer timezones (Adelaide UTC+9.5, Marquesas Islands UTC -9.5 etc)

Based on his answer I provide an update that works in all timezones

```
Date.prototype.toJSON = function () {
    const offsetHoursDecimalMins = -this.getTimezoneOffset() / 60; //Will give 9.5 for Adelaide Australia (UTC +9.5) and -9.5 for Marquesas Islands ( UTC -9.5)
    const sign= offsetHoursDecimalMins>0?'+':'-';
    const nAbsOffsetHours = Math.abs(Math.trunc(offsetHoursDecimalMins)); //Absolute value of offset hours with decimal truncated
                      
    const offsetMins = Math.abs(this.getTimezoneOffset() % 60); //Will give 30 for Adelaide Australia and 30 for Marquesas Islands
    const strUTCOffset = `${sign}${nAbsOffsetHours.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${offsetMins.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`; //"-09:30" for Marquesas Islands
                    
    /*The method Date.toISOString() returns UTC time in the format "2025-08-19T23:15:32.000Z", 
    but we want Local Time in this same format. To achieve this we create a new 
    date object (we don't want to change this one), and then add the offset hours
    and mins and call toISOString() on this new object*/
                    
    const correctedDate = new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(),
        this.getDate(), this.getHours(), this.getMinutes(), this.getSeconds(),
        this.getMilliseconds());
                    
    correctedDate.setHours(this.getHours() + offsetHoursDecimalMins); //Will add Hours and Mins (e.g 9.5 for Adelaide, -9.5 for Marquesas Islands )
                
    const x = correctedDate.toISOString().replace('Z', '');
    return `${x}${strUTCOffset}`;

    };
```