# DateTime converts to GMT in JSON object automatically

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datetime

I have a JQuery function like this

```
function (){
           alert($scope.modal.ondutytime);

            var data = {
                        "OnDutyTime": $scope.modal.ondutytime,
                        "Comments": ""
                       };

            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

The `$scope` contains all the values which I set in angularJs view. The problem is that the first `alert` shows local `ondutytime` date & time as

```
Tue Oct 06 2015 20:30:44 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
```

but when I create a JSON object `data` and then alert it after stringify, it shows UTC date & time (5 hours difference)

```
{
    "OnDutyTime": "2015-10-06T15:33:10.903Z"
    "comments":""
}
```

How can I ensure that it do not convert to GMT?

EDIT:
I also tried this

```
new Date('2015-10-06T15:33:10.903Z')
```

it is showing me local date & time, however I have to supply it `$scope.modal.ondutytime` which already contains my local date & time. So when I write the above line as

```
new Date($scope.modal.ondutytime)
```

it again shows UTC date & time.

Comment: it is setting proper `iso string`, pass that into `new Date()` and alert ...will be the same as the first.  Try `new Date().toJSON()` in your console and `new Date().toISOString()` .. will be same

Comment: `new Date($scope.modal.ondutytime).toJSON()` it also converts to UTC but I don't need any other date. I need local date.

Comment: it's not UTC it's an iso date. What format are you looking for?

Comment: I want format local for Pakistan, that is `GMT+0500`.

Comment: did you even try `alert(new Date('2015-10-06T15:33:10.903Z'))`? It's the same thing

Comment: `new Date($scope.modal.ondutytime).toString()` it solved my issue, thanks for your help, you guided me towards that. Post it as answer please.

Comment: @liaqatali - The output of `toString` is highly implementation dependent.  It doesn't belong in JSON.  You should use ISO. If you want ISO as local time with offset, then see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31104671/634824

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while dealing with brazilian timezone (GMT-3) and trying to save a "new Date()" at localstorage. The solution that I found was to change the prototype of javascript "Date()" to make the browser's timezone as javascript's default. Of course that is not a very good thing to do, but depending of what are you needs, it may help.

You can find the code that I used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096130/how-to-json-stringify-a-javascript-date-and-preserve-timezone).

As you'll see, this Stackoverflow's question has more than one solution for this problem, including the use of the "Moment JS", which is a very popular library for handling time.