# javascript moment.js format date

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing in accordance with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096130/how-to-json-stringify-a-javascript-date-and-preserve-timezone) question and I need to format my resulting time string. I use bootstrap datetimepicker and moment.js and I have this code:

```
$("#datetimepicker2").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    console.log('date2: ' + e.date.format('MM.DD.YYYY HH:mm:ss') );
    end_date = e.date;
    end_date.toJSON = function(){ return moment(this).format(); };
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(end_date));
```

My problem is that I receive

```
"2017-06-20T17:29:05+03:00"
```

while I need something like this:

```
"2017-06-20T17:29:05.013Z"
```

Any ideas how to get it would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Well then go read the moment.js documentation and find out what format specifiers are available …?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the moment object to js date and use toISOString() on that.
moment().toDate().toISOString();

Comment: the problem is that timezone is not preserved when overriding `toJSON` method

Answer (score 0):

You can add .tz() before .format() and pass in the timezone inside .tz("America/New_York"), etc.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datetimepicker2").datepicker();
  $("#datetimepicker2").on("change", function(e) {
    console.log(moment().utc($(this).val()).format());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
Date: <input type="text" id="datetimepicker2" />
```

Comment: does not work, saying `Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`. Any ideas what this could be? I am overriding a `toJSON` method in order to preserve timezone