# Angular Material Datepicker Timezone ignore?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, timezone, angular-material

I'm trying to get a date for flights from the user and the datepicker always sets the date as datetime object with the user's timezone, resulting in a wrong date sent to server.
tried to use `ng-model-options="{ timezone: 'utc' }"`

but then the user see the wrong date after choosing the date (the date displayed as a day before what the user chose).

How can I tell datepicker to completely ignore timezone  - if not possible what can I do on FE / BE to convert this date to non timezone date ?

I know I can convert it to Posix on FE but once I do it the datepicker screams that it needs date object.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Take a look to this library: https://momentjs.com/ it's used to manage dates in JS (you can use in FE and in BE with node), see the api doc, you can convert timezones and whatever you want, i hope it will be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same issue and I ended us using this code

```
Date.prototype.toJSON = function () {
   var timezoneOffsetInHours = -(this.getTimezoneOffset() / 60); //UTC minus local time
   var sign = timezoneOffsetInHours >= 0 ? '+' : '-';
   var leadingZero = (timezoneOffsetInHours < 10) ? '0' : '';

   //It's a bit unfortunate that we need to construct a new Date instance 
   //(we don't want _this_ Date instance to be modified)
   var correctedDate = new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), 
   this.getDate(), this.getHours(), this.getMinutes(), this.getSeconds(), 
   this.getMilliseconds());
   correctedDate.setHours(this.getHours() + timezoneOffsetInHours);
   var iso = correctedDate.toISOString().replace('Z', '');

   return iso + sign + leadingZero + Math.abs(timezoneOffsetInHours).toString() + ':00';
}
```

its from this other SO question [How to JSON stringify a javascript Date and preserve timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096130/how-to-json-stringify-a-javascript-date-and-preserve-timezone#answer-36643588)