# .toJson() converts date to UTC

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have datepicker and want to send a date to my rest service. While debug I see a date and it is valid.

[image: object]

But when I do .toJSON() to send it to service, Angular converts date to UTC and send it like this:

[image: htttp request]

How to send valid date?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096130/how-to-json-stringify-a-javascript-date-and-preserve-timezone

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486476/json-stringify-changes-time-of-date-because-of-utc

Comment: It is the same date (just represented in a different time zone), isn't it?

Comment: Henry. Yes - this is the date, but function converted it to UTC, so in my case date changed -1 day (-2 hours to be precise)...

Answer (score 0):

Done!

Transform on datepipe did the trick

> ```
> let dp = new DatePipe('en-EN' );
> dp.transform(this.MyDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Before sending date to rest service use:

```
var variableToSendToRestService = yourDateVariable.toLocaleString();
```

This will convert 'yourDateVariable' (which is date object) object to string using your local settings.

For more please refer:

[toLocaleString() reference for Date](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/tolocalestring-date)