# Date result shows wrong

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular7

Json result goes wrong

```
vr_date :Date

alert(this.vr_date ) // Result Shows Thu Feb 07 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0400

var json = JSON.stringify(this.vr_date);

alert(json); // Result Shows 2019-02-06T20:00:00.000Z see the date goes wrong
```

the output day shows 06 instead of 07

Please find the application here 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eavwul?file=app%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts

Comment: This is due to the different timezone, see

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486476/json-stringify-changes-time-of-date-because-of-utc

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096130/how-to-json-stringify-a-javascript-date-and-preserve-timezone/31104671

Answer (score 1):

One Date is UTC and the other GMT+0400.

Comment: how to change utc to gmt for date picker?

Comment: maybe adding
    ng-model-options="{timezone: 'utc'}"
to the <input> tag helps