# JS Convert array of dates with timezone to UTC or GMT + 0

Tags: javascript, json, timezone-offset

OK.. So I have this plugin that generates for me an array of dates. The problem is I cannot modify this plugin as it's embedded in the apps core and it takes data from a central database.

So here's the issue, the array of dates has the local timezone offset applied, so basically elements look like this:

```
0: Thu Apr 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora de verano de Europa occidental)
1: Fri Apr 12 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora de verano de Europa occidental)
```

I need to pass this array to a web service (using axios), so when I do

```
JSON.stringify(MyArray)
```

The value is converted to a text format time with the timezone offset applied:

```
"2019-04-10T23:00:00.000Z"
```

As you can see, instead of showing `00:00:00` it shows `23:00:00` and the day before the actual date, as the timezone offset is applied

Is there any workaround? maybe something to convert the full array to GMT or make `JSON.stringify` to ignore the timezone??

Comment: You could try using something like *moment.js*: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: What is the actual data in your array of dates?

Comment: Do you still want your GMT +1 to be included or just ignore it at all?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096130/how-to-json-stringify-a-javascript-date-and-preserve-timezone)?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

So; let's say you have this Array of dates coming in from JSON:

```
// WE ASSUME THIS IS A SAMPLE ARRAY FROM A SLICE OF YOUR JSON DATA
[
    Thu Apr 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora de verano de Europa occidental),
    Fri Apr 12 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora de verano de Europa occidental)
]
```

You may want to run the Array into a `map` Function and within the `map` Function, convert the GMT Dates into the appropriate Date (say UTC or whatsoever). Here's how:

```
// FIRST ASSIGN THE DATE ARRAY TO A VARIABLE SO YOU CAN REFERENCE IT EASILY.
const dateArray =  [
    Thu Apr 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora de verano de Europa occidental),
    Fri Apr 12 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora de verano de Europa occidental)
]; // THIS WOULD IMPLY WHATSOEVER VARIABLE HOLDS YOUR DATE ARRAY....

// TO CONVERT THE DATE TO SAY UTC OR SO, YOU COULD DO THAT WITHIN MAP LIKE SO
const utcDate  = dateArray.map((gmtDateString) => {
    const gmtDateObj  = new Date(gmtDateString);
    return gmtDateObj.toUTCString();
});  

// NOW, YOU CAN SHIP THE `utcDate` WITH AXIOS...
// YOU MAY HAVE TO CHECK IF YOU NEED TO STILL CALL `JSON.stringify(utcDate);`
```

Comment: I think this process does the same as JSON.Stringify. My output is a GMT time, but with the offset applied Wed, 10 Apr 2019 23:00:00 GMT

Comment: So, how would you like your Date to be formatted in the end? Do you want a Date in the Format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS` ie `2019-04-11 21:30:15`? Or rather; could you (please) **specify** the **END DATE-FORMAT** you are aiming for?

Comment: End date Format I'm aiming for: ```Thu Apr 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT``` I just want to remove the time zone offset, but keep the original format